# Adding C++ static libraries to XCode 8.2

Tags: c++, xcode, build

I needed to include several static (.a) libraries to my project. I tried to add the library path in TARGET-Build Settings-Search Paths-Library Search Paths as "($SRCROOT)/lib/" (without quotes), but it does not work.

I managed to make it working by including the names explicitly in TARGET-Build Phases-Link Binary With Libraries.

Is there a way to include the library path without explicitly listing every library?